# Uso correto do artigo em palavras / serviços em outra língua

Tags: estrangeirismos

Às vezes, conversando no dia a dia, costumo me deparar com uma dúvida quando preciso me referir a uma palavra em outro idioma.

Por exemplo:

> O novo filme do Thor acabou de estrear [ ] Netflix

O correto seria **no** Netflix, visto que é um serviço de *streaming* de vídeos?

Ou seria **na** Netflix, já que é uma plataforma de *streaming* de vídeos?

Comment: Guilherme, queres saber a regra geral? Se for isso deves dar mais exemplos, para evitar que respostas se foquem no caso Netflix. Ou queres saber a regra no caso específico do Netflix? Se for isso, deves re-escrever o título e corpo da pergunta - porque pareces estar interessado no caso geral.

Comment: Em princípio será "na" Netflix, porque se trata de uma marca estrangeira (também se diria "na H&M", "na Nestlé", "na Target", "na HBO", "na BMW" etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta tem uma resposta bem simples:

[image]
Bom, deixando de lado a brincadeira da empresa, a segunda opção é a correta, se diz "A Netflix" por se tratar de uma plataforma

Comment: Sem a brincadeira da empresa, esta resposta só diz que «se diz "A Netflix" por se tratar de uma plataforma». Mas isto não traz nada que não esteja já na pergunta... mais ainda, a pergunta já estabelece a dúvida entre "a plataforma Netflix" e "o serviço Netflix". Então, Gabriel, como achas que isto responde à pergunta? Podes reformular para ser mais explícito? :)